# Express, how to make a route handle empty parameter?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

How do I specify a route with a parameter that can be empty?

e.g. `/:one?/:two?` handles `/1/2`, but does not handle `//2`, how do I a make a route to catch both the uris?

Comment: None of them are required - `//`, `/1/`, and `/1/2` should all work

Comment: If `one` is empty the request becomes `/2`, not `//2`, and what you have done will serve `/2` if `one` is empty.

Comment: so in this case use regex

Comment: @NaeemShaikh, can you please give an example of a regexp that would keep named parameters?

Comment: nope.. i m not that good with regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.get(/\/(.*)\/(.*)/, function(req, res) {
    var one = req.params[0];
    var two = req.params[1];
});
```

```
/a/b => {0:'a', 1:'b'}
/a/  => {0:'a', 1:'' }
//b  => {0:'' , 1:'b'}
//   => {0:'' , 1:'' }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this keeping parameter names?

Comment: You mean `req.params.one/two`? I'm afraid not. When you use regex you can't use named parameters.

Comment: Sorry, but the //b  => {0:'' , 1:'b'} return instead a 404

Answer (score 2):

Long time since the question was asked, but I had the same problem and found a different solution using named parameters:

```
app.get('/:one(.{0,})/:two(.{0,})', (req, res) => {
  const one = req.params.one;
  const two = req.params.two;
});
```

Inside the paranthesis there is a regex specification of the named parameter. Note the comment in the Express documentation:

> In Express 4.x, the * character in regular expressions is not interpreted in the usual way. As a workaround, use {0,} instead of *. This will likely be fixed in Express 5.